# IE8 shows blank page after meta refresh, although the HTML is fully loaded

Tags: internet-explorer-8

We're experiencing a strange problem in IE8 with our website. Sometimes our homepage stays entirely blank, although the HTML is fully loaded. Also, the mouse pointer responds to buttons and links even though they are not displayed. When we hover over a place where there should be a button or link, the mouse pointer responds like there was an actual link or button. It is as if IE8 has rendered the entire page, but doesn't display it. We are experiencing this problem quite randomly on different machines in IE8.

I have been reading many forum topics about this behaviour, but didn't find a solution yet. But I do have some pointers. It should be related to the fact that the CMS we use uses a meta refresh. The page we serve at the root of our domain looks like this:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>redirect</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=/web/show">
 </head>
 <body></body>
</html>
```

When we go to our domain example.com and we are forwarded to example.com/web/show, then this problem sometimes occurs. When we go to example.com/web/show directly, this problem never occurs, so it must have something to do with the refresh.

- In Firefox we can see that /web/show returns response code 200.
- In IE8 "Allow META REFRESH" is enabled in the security settings.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: We have isolated the problem to the use of selectivizr.js.... We are using 1.0.3b and are going to try some other versions.

Comment: More info is to be found here: https://github.com/keithclark/selectivizr/issues/13

Comment: You shouldn't use META REFRESH for redirection unless you want your site to be slow. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/meta-refresh-causes-additional-http-requests.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We resolved the issue by removing @font-face.

Comment: This saved my can a few days before a big launch. When our website was viewed in IE8 within our staging environment, every so often there would be a blank screen. For example, we opened up 10 tabs of the same website and maybe 3 of tabs showed a blank screen. When we viewed source, the HTML was there but the page simply wasn't rendering. Once we removed @font-face, everything was fine again. 

Oddly enough our server admin tells us that font-formats were not accepted on our staging web server. This may be related to the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Glad to hear that you solved the problem. I had the same issue and was looking desperately for a solution during the last 3 hours, until I realized that for IE8 i had to define

```
html, body {
    position: static;
}
```

instead of `position: relative;`

Maybe this will save somebody 3 hours of headache.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same issue when I used `bootstrap-webpack`, finally I fixed this by moving `@font-face` declarations to the HTML head. Thanks [FlyingDR](https://github.com/keithclark/selectivizr/issues/30#issuecomment-5379856).